# how to pass json array to select query

Tags: php, arrays, json, function

I have json array as below

```
$q=[{"con0":0},{"con1":1},{"con2":2}]
```

I want to pass this array to select query where query is as follows

```
$query="select * from table_name where con0='0' and con1='1' and con2='2'";
```

Shall we use json array to create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two tricks are to turn the json into a php array via `json_decode` and then use `reset()` and `key()` functions to get the column and condition. Here is the live example:
http://ideone.com/wp1kb1 you can read more about `key`  http://php.net/key and `reset` http://php.net/reset

```
    <?php


    $q='[{"con0":0},{"con1":1},{"con2":2}]';

    $ar = json_decode($q, true);

    $where = array();
    foreach ($ar as $condition) {
      $value = reset($condition);
        $column = key($condition); 
        $where[] = " `$column` = " . (int) $value;

    }
    $whereString = implode(' AND', $where);
    $query="select * from table_name where $whereString";
    echo "\n $query \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` to make this an object/array and then use a loop to make a string for that and append to the sql query.

Comment: Shall i pass direct json object to Query like->

$query="select * from table_name where ".$q;

Answer (score 0):

Loop the **JSON** decoded data inside a `foreach`, then grab the key-value pair , store them in an array and after the end of the loop, do an `implode()` on the array with `AND` and now pass the string to your query as shown.

```
$json='[{"con0":0},{"con1":1},{"con2":2}]';
$qstr=array();
foreach(json_decode($json,true) as $k=>$arr)
{
    $qstr[]="`".key($arr)."`"." = ".$arr[key($arr)];
}
$qstr = implode(' AND ',$qstr); //looks like `con0` = 0 AND `con1` = 1 AND `con2` = 2

$query="select * from table_name where ".$qstr;
```